# RESTful API: Is it more practical to pass in parent resource locators in the request body instead of in the URI?

Tags: http, web, rest, restful-url

Suppose we have are building a REST API for a job listings app where a user can apply for a job.

Instead of making JobApplication a nested URI resource like so:
[image]

It would be made a top-level resource:
[image]

Of course, in the case of the latter, the JobVacancy's id is still included in the request but is passed through the request body instead of the URI.

Why the latter approach? Because it saves the client the inconvenience of having to know the parent resource's id for 3 of the routes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in the end, this is just a matter of standard. Both solutions will work fine, however, the first approach is more readable closer to the real-world operations, the applications are always related to some job vacancies.

Moreover, you need to consider if, in your system, you always access the applications starting from a job vacancy. If this is true, I believe that the first approach is much more clear, because the relation of dependencies between the two entities is clearly expressed in the signature of the method.